# CSS image transition

Tags: css, css-transitions

Is it really impossible to let CSS recognize the change in src of an image and apply the correct transition, without resulting to the hacks that I find online, such as just placing several images over each other or using a combination of src and background?

It seems like such a deficiency as images are one of any website's main elements (divs, images, text). My question is: is it really not supported directly, and if not, why?

Comment: What have you tried? but CSS is a stylesheet and shouldnt have any knowledge of the image src attribute tag - but it should for the background-image: css attribute. if you want to change the src tag then you maybe need to look at something with javascript

Comment: Despite it is usually not recommended to use such technique, you can apply specific CSS rules to `img` tags with certain values of `src` attributes. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible.
You can create CSS rules to match elements by certain values of certain attributes. This is a very rarely used feature of CSS selectors but it is supported since CSS 2.1 and I've even used it once - works in all browsers, including IE7. You can read more about this here: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#attribute-selectors

Example:

```
img[src='one.png'] { ... }
img[src='two.png'] { ... }
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/dJJqf/

Comment: Just want an image to change. So I change it's SRC property. The change shouldnt be abrupt, but instead show a nice fade out of the old image, and fade in the new image. That's all. But it now seems confirmed that this cannot be done with JUST html/css. _Didnt know that you could do that thing with css selectors per src tho, so thanks for that, at least learned something_

Answer (score 0):

CSS cannot alter the DOM. So no, you can't edit the src attributes.

You can, of course, use either JavaScript, or use CSS backgrounds (`background-image`) which can be changed from CSS.

Alternatively, use a lot of `<img>` tags in HTML, then use CSS to move these around.

Comment: It seems I have not been clear, sorry for that.

What I mean is, when I alter for example the LEFT property of a div via JS, then CSS picks this up and applies the transition I asked for in my CSS-stylesheet for that particular div.

When I use the same JS script to alter an image (by changing the src), CSS does not pick it up, and does nothing with the transition I have defined for that image in my CSS stylesheet.

My question is if this is not supported, and if it isnt, then I am curious to know WHY not?